# Gridview return only one row

Tags: android, datagridview

I am using a **GridView** in a **Relative layout**. I want the **GridView** to show 
up as tall as needed to show all the rows. However, I am seeing only 
one row when set (**layout_width=MATCH_PARENT** and) 
**layout_height=WRAP_CONTENT**. If I set layout_height to a size that 
equals mulitple rows, then I do see those rows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_month"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textv_month_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="7dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/top_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textv_month_name"
        android:background="@drawable/calendar_top_small"
        android:clickable="false" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridv_inner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top_bar"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="7"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
         >
    </GridView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/monthBtn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any Help will be appreciable

Comment: Post your xml file and code also.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/P5zlnvpbQLU

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This is a very useful answer.

The GridView didn’t like the wrap_content of its height when it was put in a vertically tight space; it only showed a single row of items (scrolling all content in that single row).

The short version of my fix includes sub classing the GridView and overriding the onMeasure method. The essence of the fix focuses on setting the measured height spec to a ridiculously large number.

MyGridview.Java

```
   package com.arun.calendar;

   import android.content.Context;
   import android.util.AttributeSet;
   import android.widget.GridView;

   public class MyGridView extends GridView {

 public MyGridView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int heightSpec;

        if (getLayoutParams().height == LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) {

            // The two leftmost bits in the height measure spec have
            // a special meaning, hence we can't use them to describe height.
            heightSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                    Integer.MAX_VALUE >>2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        }
        else {
            // Any other height should be respected as is.
            heightSpec = heightMeasureSpec;
        }

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightSpec);
    }
}
```

And the new XML file

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_month"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textv_month_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="7dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/top_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textv_month_name"
        android:background="@drawable/calendar_top_small"
        android:clickable="false" />

    <com.arun.calendar.MyGridView
        android:id="@+id/gridv_inner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top_bar"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="7"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/monthBtn"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And in java file

```
 MyGridView  viewHolder.gridView = (MyGridView) v.findViewById(R.id.gridv_inner);
```

Comment: LOL @ "this is a very useful answer"

Comment: you are a life saver! :)

Comment: Excellent answer! Thanks!