# GridView inside other GridView - only one row is shown

Tags: android, gridview

I want to make custom calendar, and for this I'm using a `GridView` (with 12 cells for months) with embedded `GridView`s for every month (showing days of months). I did very simple layout and code just to check how it looks. The problem is that I get 12 cells, but each of them shows only 1 row of inner grid (of month). So it shows like "`0 1 2 3 4 5 6`" for every cell of 12 (months).

First, it was worse - it was showing just single row of outer grid with single  rows of inner grids. After some experimenting, I solved this problem: the issue was with that my main activity had root element of some special class (this was auto-generated by Android studio), I have changed it to `LinearLayout` and it started showing all cells of outer grid, but still just 1 row of the inner. First, my inner layouts were wrapped in `RelativeLayout`, I changed them all to `LinearLayout` hoping this will fix it - but there is no change. I also experimented a bit with widths and heights with no luck, and I have no idea what to try next.

Here are my layouts:

activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/calendar_year"></include>

</LinearLayout>
```

calendar_year (outer grid)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <GridView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/grid_year"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
</LinearLayout>
```

calendar_month (inner grid)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <GridView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/grid_month"
        android:numColumns="7"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
</LinearLayout>
```

calendar_day (cell content)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/text_day"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
</LinearLayout>
```

onCreate of MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ((GridView) this.findViewById(R.id.grid_year)).setAdapter(new YearGridAdapter(getApplicationContext()));
}
```

Outer grid's adapter:

```
public class YearGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public YearGridAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 12;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_month, parent, false);
        }
        GridView monthView = (GridView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_month);
        monthView.setAdapter(new MonthGridAdapter(context));
        return convertView;
    }

    private Context context;
}
```

Inner grid's adapter:

```
public class MonthGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public MonthGridAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 30;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_day, parent, false);
        }
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_day)).setText(Integer.toString(position));
        return convertView;
    }

    private Context context;
}
```

Comment: if you scroll down on the inner gridview does the other lines showing?

Comment: vspallas, there is no scroll and I don't see any possibility to scroll. It just shows numbers in rows without any visible boundaries etc. When I click/tap the cell - don't see any response.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably caused by having `GridView` inside of `GridView`. Since both layouts are scrollable this causes a lot of problems. You can see on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22727503/3763848) Arun Antoney's answer which may solve your problem

Comment: Hm... I saw this thread while searching for solutions, but thought it's not my case because I was never using wrap_content, I was using fill_parent or match_parent from the start. I have tried that now, and it started looking better, although there are still some problems - 1-digit numbers are Ok, but 2-digits are wrapped (line break between) and cause content overflow (with no scrolling still). But this is already much better, I just probably need to play with cell content to make it look good.

Comment: maybe if you change the line
heightSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                    Integer.MAX_VALUE >>2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
with 
heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MEASURED_SIZE_MASK,
                    MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
will make it better